# Can I use this simple debounce RC circuit for Arduino?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, resistors, circuit-design

[image]

The values for the resistor and capacitor are what I will be using. This is the circuit I will be doing because using two resistors might take up too much space. I will be replicating this circuit for 6 buttons, and the PCB that I will be using is a 5x7cm single-sided PCB through-hole. The button I will be using is a mechanical switch used in mechanical keyboards.

Comment: why not remove resistor and capacitor, use internal pullup and debounce using software?

Comment: I haven't made a circuit before so I'd like to make a proper one as my first. Other than that there isn't really, just wanted to make my life harder I guess.

Comment: How long wires? Will the capacitor be on MCU side of the wiring, or on the button side of the wiring?

Comment: @jsotola debounce using software takes resources, which is great if its spare. If hardware can be provisioned it saves on this

Comment: @Justme it's on the side of the button. I have the pcb circuit made in software if you want to take a look.

Comment: @JonRB, surely it's the other way around, though. Use software unless you absolutely cannot, at which point use hardware. The latter ups the part count and costs. It's pretty rare that an MCU is so loaded it can't spare the capacity and a timer interrupt to sample a switch every 3..10 ms or so and check for the same level over three samples.

Comment: I'll add a standard warning for attaching switches to (especially older) uC inputs.  Be aware that if you connect a switch to interrupt pin inputs, and expect to rely on software debouncing, then you may be in for a bad time.  Switch-bouncing noise on uC Interrupt pins can throw the whole uC into chaos (like some 8051's).  Just keep in mind that a little hardware debouncing may not be a bad thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't debounce -- as the other answers describe, you can use a software debounce.

The biggest problem with this circuit is that it will destroy the switch. Discharging the 100 nF capacitor with no current limit R will cause small arcing in the switch which after a few 100 (?) cycles will destroy it. You should limit the peak current spike to much less than 10 mA in general.

Comment: I didn't know it will do that. I will try to fit 2 resistors in my circuit. Just a question though, if discharging 100nf will damage the switch, do I need to add a resistor on both ends of the switch?

Comment: No, just in series with the switch. think of the capacitor as a 5 V battery (with a very short lifetime). You don't want an uncontrolled current just after the switch is closed.
You can still use just 1 resistor total if you can use the idea above with the internal pull-up.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will keep this in mind when designing a circuit.

Comment: I agree that the switch will discharge the capacitor current but that won't destroy the switch, nor damage it in anything like a few hundred cycles. Have you seen that happen to large numbers of switches yourself in <300 cycles? This circuit has been around and widely used for decades without the failures you describe.

Comment: I would never use a small keyboard button switch with gold (?) contacts and 100 nF. Perhaps < 1 nF ?

Older systems  likely have 'real' switches like 120 VAC ones and of course those will survive.

Comment: Older systems weren't all big 120 Vac switches, quite the opposite. But rather than guesswork, please can you substantiate your claim and describe where you actually saw failures across large numbers of switches within <300 cycles. Thanks.

Comment: For example https://www.cherrymx.de/_Resources/Persistent/b/7/a/b/b7ab2f72bd5686e1e1e759a9f3703536d7fb1e18/EN_CHERRY_MX_RED.pdf lists 10 mA max. which is the content of my answer. The OP is using a keyboard switch, possibly like this.

Comment: *describe where you actually saw failures across large numbers of switches within <300 cycles* Unfortunately, you've avoided this direct query and answered with supposition instead twice. So it appears that you haven't seen any failures and can't remotely substantiate your claim. That's what I expected as I have seen low current switches with parallel capacitors used as standard in a many designs over a long time. Parallel capacitors don't have a history of damaging low current switches in a few hundred cycles or anything like it.

Comment: Ignore the advice if you don't believe it. –

Comment: It's not advice you're giving. You've written it as a statement of fact. "*The biggest problem with this circuit is that it will destroy the switch. Discharging the 100 nF capacitor with no current limit R will cause small arcing in the switch which after a few 100 (?) cycles will destroy it.*" Downvoting for that reason, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

That will work to remove some switch bounce.  Will it remove all of it for every switch cycle?  Maybe, maybe not.  It depends on the actual switches used.  Not all switches have a datasheet that details the bounce time.  So, all this is to say that you will want to add a software routine to debounce the switch as well.  And if you have that, you can tune it so that you don't need the external capacitor.

Comment: Yeah, I have a code that has software debounce already. Just wanna try this circuit for fun and for educational value.

Comment: @GaleDesign The rule of thumb I was taught was that switches bounce for 20ms.  I've found this to  be a wild swag.  I've had switches bounce for 10x more and less than that.  But it's a starting point if you don't have a datasheet.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is not an RC filter for debouncing actually. Because when the button is pressed, R1 aren't in the current path while C1 are discharging. It will bounce due to this.

Instead you can use MCU internal pull-up, when make an RC filter from the pin to a button (and surely remove external +Vcc pull-up). Even while internal pull-up are very weak, with some software filtering it can provide stable results on such a small board. Make sure to get values good enough considered there is also internal pull-up resistor involved.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNpZPf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Consider you have to tune you RC values based on MCU internal pull-up resistance (it should be noted in the data sheet). R1 should be high enough to discharge C1 smoothly to debounce. But also low enough compared to internal pull-up resistor R2 to be able to discharge it to enough voltage.

Another thing is to pick a resistor chip arrays. Those have a few resistors inside one package and usually saves some space compared to stand alone resistors when you need a few of the same value. At least it's pretty noticeable with SMD parts. As noted by @Theodore in comment below, you can pick those with common terminal and combine with previous schematics (swapping SW1 with R1 as noted, I won't edit schematic now to avoid confusion and it's irrelevant without using common terminal resistor array), you can save more PCB space.

Comment: Thank you for the input! Unfortunately I forgot to mention that the pcb is a through hole so I don't think I can use SMD's. Also I don't want to spend too much money as it is already.

I will try this method out. Thanks!

Comment: @GaleDesign there are also through hole resistor arrays. They don't save as much space as smd counterparts but still. Even with 1 resistor per button you can use those to save some space. And they are pretty damn cheap. Usually they cost same pennies that a single resistor instead.

Comment: Also worth noting: if you swap the resistor and switch, all 6 resistors will be tied to ground.  You may be able to find a suitable resistor pack IC with all resistors sharing a common terminal (that you will connect to ground).  This is called "[bussed](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/54/4600x-776645.pdf)" configuration.  This will save several pins.

Comment: Thank you, I've never heard of those before. I'll probably use them in my next project.

Answer (score 1):

This circuit will still create bounce input. Before the switch is pressed the cap is fully charged through the resistor to the VCC supply level. As the switch is pressed and makes the very first contact, it will make/break as all mechanical switches do, so the voltage on the cap is shorted only briefly (on the make part) but will not instantly deplete and jumps back up (on the break part). So the logic input will be "1", then bouncing "1" to "0", then settling on "0".

For the fewest number of parts solution, remove the cap and use a software debounce function.